# How to Increase the size of Panel scrollbar?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

How can I increase the size of `Panel`'s scrollbar? There is not any property available for scrollbar size in Panel control.

I know this can be achieved using GDI+ in .Net.

Comment: Do you want it to be wider than normal scroll bar?

Comment: Yes, basically the application used for tablet devices and user scroll the panel control by finger touch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the .Net Panel control doesn't offer this feature.

If you wanna paint yourself you should use GDI / GDI+
In addition, you still need to handle the hit test things to respond the mouse messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate controls [VScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.vscrollbar.aspx) and [HScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.hscrollbar.aspx) - it is possible to set their width.
You can also code your own custom scroll bar like this [Core Custom Scrollbar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7791/Core-Custom-Scrollbar-Class).

Both solutions requires some additional work, as you wont be able to use `Panel.AutoScroll` property. You could put `VScrollBar` and `HScrollBar` on a `UserControll` and use that as your "Custom Scrollable Panel" for better functionality.